# CPU cache hit time

Tags: memory-management, hardware, cpu-cache

I am reading "computer organization and design the hardware/software interface" in spanish edition, and I have run into an exercise that I can not solve. The exercise is about memory hierarchy, specifically caches.

The exercise says:

> If 2.5 ns are required to access labels in an N-way associative cache, 4 ns for access data, 1 ns for hit/failure comparison and 1 ns to return the data selected by the processor in case of success.
>
> 1. The critical path in a cache hit, is given by the time to determine whether there has been success or time data access?
> 2. What is the hit latency of the cache? (successful case).
> 3. What would be the latency of success in the cache if both the access time to labels and the data matrix is 3 ns?

I'll try to answer the questions with all I know about memories.

To access a data saved in the cache, the first thing I have to do is find the line using the index field of some address. Once the memory system have found the line, I need to compare the label field of my address with the label field of the cache. If they match, then it is a hit and I have to return the data, and displace an amount of data in the line determined by the offset field of the address and then return the data to the processor.

That implies that the cache will take 8.5 ns. But I have been thinking in another way that chaches can do it: if I get the desired line (2.5 ns) then now I can access de data, and in parallel, I can evaluate the condition of iquality. So, the time will be 4.5 ns. So, one of these are the result of the second question. Which of these results is correct?

For the first question, the critical path will be the operation that takes the larger amount of time; if the cache takes 4.5 to get the data, then the critical path will be access the labels in the cache - comparison - return the data. Otherwise, it will be the entire process.

For the last question, if the critical path is the entire process then it will take 8ns. Else, it will take 5ns (labels access in the cache, comparison, return the data).

This is true?, and what about a fully assoctive cache?, and a direct mapping cache?

The problem is that I do not know what things the cache do first and what next or in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text does'nt say anything about if it's a cache in a uniprocessor system/multiprocessor system or what the cache does in parallel you can safely assume that it performs the whole process in case of a cache hit. Instinctively I think it does'nt make sense to access the data and compare hit/miss in parallel, what if it's a miss? then then the data access is unneccessary and you increase the latency of the cache miss.

So then you get the following sequence in case of a cache hit:

1. Access label (2.5ns)
2. Compare hit/miss (1ns)
3. Access the data (4ns)
4. Return the data to the program requesting it (1ns)

**Total:** 2.5 + 1 + 4 +1 = 8.5ns

With this sequence we get (as you already now) the following answers to the questions:

1. **Answer:** The critical path in a cache hit is to access the data and return it 4+1=5 (ns), compared to determine wether the cache lookup was a success: 2.5 + 1 = 3.5 (ns)
2. **Answer:** 8.5ns
3. **Answer:** 3 + 1 + 3 + 1 = 8ns

> If I get the desired line (2.5 ns) then now I can access de data, and
>   in parallel, I can evaluate the condition of iquality. So, the time
>   will be 4.5 ns

I don't see how you get 4.5ns? If you assume that the access of data and the hit/failure comparison is executed in parallel then you get: 2.5 + 4 + 1 = 7ns in case of a cache hit. You would also get 7ns in case of a cache miss, compared to if you don't access memory until you know if it's a cache miss, then you get a miss latency of 2.5 +1 = 3.5ns instead, which makes it very uneffective to try to parallelize the hit/miss comparison with data access.

If you assume that the access of the label **and** the hit/miss comparison is done in parallel with data access you get: 4 + 1 = 5ns in case of a cache hit.

Obviously you cannot return the data in parallel with fetching the data, but if you imagine that would be possible  and you access the label **and** do comparison **and** return the data in parallel with accessing the data then you get: 2.5 + 1 + 1 = 4.5ns.

> what about a fully assoctive cache?, and a direct mapping cache?

A N-way associative cache (as the question refers to) *is* a fully associative cache. This means that cache blocks can be placed anywhere in the cache. Hence it's very flexible, but it also means that when we want to lookup a memory address in the cache we need to compare the tag with every block in the cache to know if the memory address we're looking for is cached or not. Consequently we get slower lookup time.

In a direct mapped cache, every cache block can only go in one spot in the cache. That spot is computed by looking at the memory address and computing the index-part of the address. Thus a direct-mapped cache can give very quick lookups but is not very flexible. Depending on the cache size, cache blocks can be replaced very often.

The terminology in the question is a bit confusing, "label" is usually called "tag" when speaking of cpu-caches.